# Is there any Reporting Engine which supports MarkDown or it`s HTML-Subset?

Tags: html, reporting, markdown

I am looking for a Reporting Engine which supports MarkDown or the HTML-Subset needed to display MarkDown formatted Text correctly, is there any?

I already tried Crystal Reports, but learned during my Test's that `<ul>` and `<ol>` are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

[myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting tool allows you to include arbirarty HTML in your report output. See http://mydbr.com/doc/?cmd.html.html for details.